# Angular Send a put request correctly

Tags: angular, typescript

I wrote the put method with Express as follows, but I get an error when sending in the angular section. I know I get an error because I don't send it as an object, but I don't know how to send it as an object. Can you please help?

controller.js (backend)

```
Word.updateStatus = (wordId,status,result) => {
    sql.query('update wordstable set status = ? where id = ?',[status,wordId],(err,res)=> {
        if(err) {
            console.log('error : ',err);
            result(null,err);
            return;
        }
        if(res.affectedRows == 0 ) {
            result({kind:'not_found'},null);
            return;
        }
        result(null, res);

    })
}
```

service.ts

```
setStatus(statusId:number, statusValue:number ) {
    return this.httpService.put(`${this.url}/status/${statusId}`,statusValue);
  }
```

component.ts

```
 this.wordsService.setStatus(getWord.id,1);
```

When I tested it with Postman, it performed successfully.

http://localhost:3000/words/status/2

{
"status" : 1
}

Comment: What does the body of your Postman request look like? As you point out, it sounds like you are very close, but maybe just need to "wrap" your `statusValue` in an object of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
setStatus(statusId:number, statusValue:number ) {
 const params = new HttpParams().set('status', statusValue)
 return this.httpService.put(`${this.url}/status/${statusId}`,{parmas});
}
```

Hope useful

Comment: Elaborate on "it didn't work". What happened? What was sent? Was there an error? If so, then what error it was?

Comment: It works correctly with HttpParams, but when it comes to return, the status does not change.

Comment: @MichaelScott So it work, i think your api not update statut that why you not get change in return

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your objective is to send a JSON of this shape

```
{ "status" : 1 }
```

then you should `PUT` an object, not a primitive. Therefore

```
setStatus(statusId:number, status: number) {
    return this.httpService.put(`${this.url}/status/${statusId}`, { status });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered such a result when I tried;

```
setStatus(statusId:number, statusValue) {
    
    const params = new HttpParams().set('status',statusValue)
    console.log(params.get('status')) // incoming value: 1  this is correct 
    console.log(`${this.url}/status/${statusId}`,params) // http://localhost:3000/words/status/1
    return this.httpService.put(`${this.url}/status/${statusId}`,params); // still status 0 
  }
```